# Using Jquery UI Datepicker when using .load to insert page fragments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble getting the jquery UI datepicker to initialize. I can initialize it just fine on a stand alone html file but when I use the jquery .load function to parse html to an existing container; the datepicker will not initialize. I'm using bootstrap v.3 and have tried a variety of jquery versions.

Here is my html (I have omitted the top part which is loaded from the index).

```
    <link href="css/customApp.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TheWarOnCost.com</a>
            </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li id="dashNav1" class="active"><a onclick="dashNav(1);">The War Room</a></li>
                <li id="dashNav2"><a onclick="dashNav(2);">Record New Battle</a></li>
                <li id="dashNav3"><a onclick="dashNav(3);">Remove Battle</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li id="dashNav4"><a onclick="dashNav(4);">Goal Tracker</a></li>
                <li id="dashNav5"><a onclick="dashNav(5);">Year to Date Report</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
            <div id="mainContent">
                <!-- Main content inserted here on nav click -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my html for the loaded page fragment

```
<div id="addTripInsert">
<h1 class="page-header">New Battle Stats</h1>
<div class="row placeholders">
    <div id="clearFix">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 placeholder aTiC_Wrap" style="xbackground-color:rgba(0,0,255,.4); height:100px;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 addTripInputs" style="background-color: rgba(66, 139, 202, .3); border-radius:10px; height:75px;">
            <svg width="40" height="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svgNum">
                <circle id="svg_1" r="16.93171" cy="20" cx="20" stroke-width="2" stroke="#428bca" fill="#ffffff"/>
                <text font-weight="bold" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Sans-serif" font-size="29" id="svg_2" y="31" x="20" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#428bca" fill="#ef3bff">1</text>
            </svg>
            <h4 class="aTi_Title" style="width:117px;">Trip Date</h4>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 aTi_content">The date this battle was waged.</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 aTi_content"><input id="datepicker"></div>
        </div>
```

The fragment is loaded with this javascript

```
function dashNav(option){

$("li").click( function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

switch(option)
{
    case 1:
        // alert('You have selected Battle Tracker which is menu option #' + option);
        $( "#mainContent" ).load( "modules/mainTracker.php #trackerInsert" );
        break;
    case 2:
        // alert('You have selected Add shopping trip which is menu option #' + option);
        $( "#mainContent" ).load( "modules/addTrip.php #addTripInsert" );
        break;
    case 3:
        // alert('You have selected Remove shopping trip which is menu option #' + option);
        $( "#mainContent" ).load( "modules/removeTrip.php #remTripInsert" );
        break;
    case 4:
        // alert('You have selected Goal Tracker which is menu option #' + option);
        $( "#mainContent" ).load( "modules/goalTracker.php #goalTrackerInsert" );
        break;
    case 5:
        // alert('You have selected Year to date savings which is menu option #' + option);
        $( "#mainContent" ).load( "modules/ytdSavings.php #ytdsInsert" );
        break;
    default:
}
}

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

Basically, the outer template of the page is rendered using a php kernel. Once the outer template is loaded, it loads the first page fragment (not shown). Once the user clicks on the second nav option (addTrip) it uses .load to inject that fragment in to the main content div in the original markup. Is this messing with the initialization?

Sorry if this sounds like a duplicate question. I did not find anything that adequately handled this case.

Answer (score 0):

when  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); method is getting called there is no datepicker input in body hence datepicker is not initialized. You can attach callback to load method to assign datepicker:

```
.....
  case 1:
    // alert('You have selected Battle Tracker which is menu option #' + option);
    $( "#mainContent" ).load( "modules/mainTracker.php #trackerInsert", function(){
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();  
    } );
    break;
..........
```

Comment: It says that datepicker is not a function when I try it this way.

Comment: That's what's weird to me. I have tried it several ways and I can't seem to get it to work. I think the solution to this problem for me is to change the way the page is constructed. I figure a more traditional page construction is the right way to go.

Comment: Yes. May be alternatively you can try to move  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();  in each page getting loaded thourgh AJAX.